# What makes a molecule a polyatomic ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecules

I checked the Wikipedia page, but it did not seem to provide a very intuitive explanation.

What distinguishes a molecule such that it behaves like a polyatomic ion? I understand that it is a covalent bond, but what distinguishes it from other covalent bonds that allow it to act like one element. Why does it have a *charge*, unlike many other compounds (ionic and covalent)?

Answer (score 2):

A polyatomic ion is simply a molecule that has gained or lost one or more electrons, thus acquiring a net charge. This can occur due to oxidation or reduction of the molecule, by association of an atomic ion with a neutral molecule or by autoionisation of a neutral species into a anion/cation pair.

A concrete example of the latter two processes is the autoionisation of water, which to a first-order approximation may be considered as $\ce{2H_{2}O <=> H_{3}O^{+} + OH^{-}}$. This is coincidentally an example (one of many) of an aqueous reaction involving covalency with a water molecule, addressing in part one of your other [questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/why-doesnt-water-play-a-role-in-reactions-in-aqueous-reactions).

There also exist polyatomic ions known as [zwitterions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion) (from German 'zwitter', meaning 'hermaphrodite' or 'hybrid') which possess localised opposite charges on different atoms, but are neutral overall.

Comment: Thanks. Why are polyatonic ions treated as a singular element though? (as in the case of double displacement, single displacement etc)

Comment: @FarhadYusufali - Because for study purposes you have been shown a subset of reactions to study that don't involve the covalent bonds within the ions being broken. Instead, I imagine you are looking at reactions involving ionic bonds being broken in solution.